# How to create a public album in Facebook without alerting everyone?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I was at this nice event with hundreds of people which are not my Facebook friends. Besides posting photos to Google Photos I made a smaller selection for Facebook so everybody can tag themselves and receive likes and such. I just did not want all my "friends" know that I created this album so I was thinking I upload it and upon finishing I change visibility to "only me". Looked OK.

When done I changed the visibility to "public" and I noticed that on my timeline there is a post about this new album, so I clicked "hide on my timeline". Not sure when it appeared there - if in the time I changed the album to public or before. Strangely Facebook asked me why I hid it, but it was my own post! So I hid it and posted a link to the album to the event page thinking only people attending to this event will see it, but no. Minutes later I started receiving likes from my friends who were not there.

Do you think there is a way to create a public photo album on Facebook silently?

Comment: it seems this may have helped if I did that before...
https://www.facebook.com/help/100522066706974

Answer (score 2):

You can not create *publicly* anything on Facebook *silently*.

Facebook gives the option of [Audience selector](https://www.facebook.com/help/332530843426690) by which yo can select the audience according to you.

In your case (as you said you don't have them in your friend list), you can create an album and select audience as ***Only me*** and tag all the people who was present in that event (Or anyone whom you want to see this album, if you are not able to tag, just ask to tagged people to tag others if they know anyone).
So this album is only visible to you and all those people who are tagged in that.

Other thing is you can create a list (if they are in your friend list) and select *custom audience* and enter the *list name* or each name one by one (whom you want to show this album). So it will be visible to only those selected people. Remember in this case also it will be visible to those who are tagged in that pic or album.

Comment: thanks. But how can anybody tag themselves in an album which is set to "only me" ? If they cannot display it, then they cannot tag themselves right? I could tag only a few people because 90% of them I don't know by name so I let them do it :) I was thinking about making a list but that would be crazy in case of hundreds of people. What do you think about the settings I mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: @Vitas: Thanks for pointing that. I corrected that in answer. :)